# C - Why substracting single characters leave a blank?

Tags: c, tabs

I tried to replace characters with substraction. It works but it leaves a blank with this method:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int c;

while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\t')
        putchar('t');
    if(c == '\t')
        c = c - '\t';
    putchar(c);
}

}
```

Its the substraction that gives the unwanted output and I couldn't figure out why.

Example input:
Hello tab       tab       tab

Output:
Hello tabt tabt tab

Goal is Hello tabttabttab.

Comment: If you are getting unwanted output, please [edit] your post to include some sample input and output you are giving/getting.

Comment: What do you want to replace the character with? And why do you think subtraction is the way to do it?

Comment: Please, provide something that compiles and indent the code properly.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to write an escaped representation of a string with tabs? Anyway, `'\t'- '\t'` is zero or the null character, which isn't a printable character. Your console might print a blank instead.

Comment: @Keon Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question with what your code supposed to do. Perhaps, updating with a sample input and an expected output might help.

Comment: I wanted to replace tabs with 't' and dont think that it must be substraction, I am just a beginner and tried it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "blank" is the result of printing NUL (`0`) character. Whenever you input `'\t'`, you are printing NUL, which is not a printable character.

```
if(c == '\t')     
    c = c - '\t';
putchar(c); // same as putchar(0); if c == '\t'
```

Perhaps, you wanted to replace tabs with `-`:

```
if(c == '\t')     
    c = '-';
putchar(c);
```